# How to share logged in user session between Rails and Zend Framework?

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, ruby, zend-framework, devise

I am trying to add a Rails application as a subdirectory of a PHP Zend Framework application. I have configured Apache to use the PHP app as the default and any requests to `/myrailsapp` go through the Rails app. Now the only problem is sharing sessions. I understand that I need to start storing the session data in the database so both applications have access to the same session information.

So how do I configure these things in Zend Framework and Rails using Devise so the logged in user can transition seemlessly between the apps?

Comment: This might sound super stupid but, do you mean have them as sub-domain , I mean, they share the same domain, don't they?

Comment: No, not subdomain. I really meant subdirectory.

Comment: Also, I think there would be another issue with trying to share sessions across subdomains if that were the case.

Comment: exactly my point. I have had done a workaround in one of my "currently LIVE" project. It was between CI and ZF. Here, the link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11839812/cross-framework-authentication-zend-codeigniter I guess, you might have to resort to something similar.