# Including Zend Library within Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, zend-framework

So I'm attempting to install some Zend Framework components mainly so I can use the google API picasa library.

I tried adding the Zend library to my

> codeigniter-> application-> libraries

and then running `$this->load->library('Zend');` but I receive

> Unable to load the requested class: zend

Then I tried doing it

```
$clientLibraryPath = '/usr/local/lib/php/Zend/Gdata';
$oldPath = set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . $clientLibraryPath);
```

### Error

```
> Exception thrown trying to access Zend/Loader.php  using
> 'use_include_path' = true. Make sure you  include Zend Framework in
> your include_path  which currently  contains:
> .:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear:/usr/local/lib/php/Zend/Gdata
```

I'm not sure on what the actual path should be **I also uploaded the Zend libary into users/local/lib/php** as well. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possible dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12255888/how-to-combine-zend-framework-and-codeigniter.

Answer (score 6):

See this:
you need to create file **Zend.php** in **libraries**
as image below:
[image]

and past this code into it:

```
if (!defined('BASEPATH')) {
    exit('No direct script access allowed');
}

class Zend
{

    public function __construct($class = NULL)
    {

        ini_set('include_path', ini_get('include_path') . PATH_SEPARATOR . APPPATH . 'libraries');

        if ($class) {

            require_once (string) $class . EXT;

            log_message('debug', "Zend Class $class Loaded");
        } else {

            log_message('debug', "Zend Class Initialized");
        }
    }

    public function load($sClassName)
    {

        require_once (string) $sClassName . EXT;

        log_message('debug', "-> Zend Class $sClassName Loaded from the library");
    }

}
```

That’s it. Now call library what you need from your method in **Controller**.
Here I show one example to load **Picasa Web Albums**.

```
    $this->load->library('zend');
    $this->zend->load('Zend/Loader');
    Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata');
    Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin');
    Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_Photos');
    Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Http_Client');
```

**With another example to load Google Spreedsheet.**

```
$this->load->library('zend');
$this->zend->load('Zend/Gdata/Spreadsheets');
$oSpreadSheet = new Zend_Gdata_Spreadsheets();
$entry = $oSpreadSheet->newCellEntry();
$cell = $oSpreadSheet->newCell();
$cell->setText('My cell value');
$cell->setRow('1');
$cell->setColumn('3');
$entry->cell = $cell;
var_dump(  $entry );
```

for more information [see this](http://yuljet.blogspot.com/2013/12/integrate-zend-framework-library-in.html)

Comment: I actually had to set EXT to ".php" to get mine to load not sure if this is a CI version 3 issue.