# Inconsistent HTTP redirect behavior between hosting environments

Tags: php, http, cakephp, redirect, http-headers

This is a follow up question to [one I asked a few days ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15257265/cakephp-2-x-sessions-behaving-inconsistently-between-local-dev-and-production/15347510) and ultimately managed to resolve myself.  While I was happy to find the underlying problem, the fact that the issue only manifested in one (of three) environments seems really odd.

The issue had to do with actions on a CakePHP 2.3.0 site that were redirecting in the controller (`$this->redirect(...);`).

Basically, redirects worked fine on my local (Mac OS X/10.6.8, Apache/2.2.17, PHP/5.3.4) development machine as well as my coworker's (Windows 7, Apache/2.4.2, PHP/5.4.3).  "add" actions inserted records into the database and then redirect to the "index" action.  User logins worked fine.  No problems, everything looked correct.

However, on our staging server (Debian GNU/Linux 6.0.6 kernel 3.2.6, Apache/2.2.22, PHP/5.3.15) any controller action that tried to redirect resulted in an HTTP 200 blank page (instead of the expected HTTP 302 redirect).

The page wasn't truly blank, there was a single line break which I ultimately found had been erroneously added before the opening PHP tag in one of my controllers.  As I understand it, the line break essentially triggered the end of header output so the `Location: ...` header couldn't be written.

Once the errant line break was found it was a quick fix, but I wonder why I didn't see the same blank page behavior on either my Mac or my coworker's Windows machine.  I'm not sure if this is a quirk between PHP or Apache versions, or what, really.  I'd be interested in anyone's theories on why things behaved the way they did.

Comment: How do you move files between machines?

Comment: We have a subversion repo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the answer to this stack overflow question: "[How to fix "Headers already sent" error in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/headers-already-sent-by-php)":

> **But it worked on the other server!?**
>
> If you didn't get the headers warning before, then the php.ini setting
>   has been changed. Output buffering then was enabled on the other
>   server, but not on the current. See previous section.

Comment: Error reporting was on for all servers and I got no error message.  I understand the "Headers already sent" bit, but why were the redirects working at all anywhere?  Shouldn't they all have failed with the blank page?  Sorry if I'm missing something in your answer.

Comment: Sorry, just reread that section on output buffering and that was in fact the configuration difference.  Thanks for the answer!