# Cakephp white screen when index action called

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.1

I'm deploying a CakePhp project that works fine in localhost but at production i have white screen when i call any index action of any controller. Debug level is 3,  no cake php error log, no httpd error log, no php error log.nothing to debug with logs.

Permissions are ok, cache folders are empty, mod_rewrite ok , white spaces deleted at the end of files...

I can call a login action but the login fails. i was debugging with print_r and echo, then i discovered that CakePhp could not initialize the session, the session_id is aways null. the method setFlash is not working. Also there is no flash messages of login fails.

Please Help Me.

Comment: White screen of death! I spent 2 days on it and i cant find a solution...

Comment: can u update your status of session after trying http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15257265/cakephp-2-x-sessions-behaving-inconsistently-between-local-dev-and-production/15287161#15287161 ?

Comment: Is the `tmp` directory writable?

Comment: session is not working with those instructions....

Comment: tmp is writable... and there are files cached there

Comment: Are you using the 'php' or 'cake' session handler? The php session handler may try to write to a shared directory outside your app, which may not be accessible. Try to change it to 'cake' so that it will be written to app/tmp/sessions configuration: https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/app/Config/core.php#L185

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem! It was a file encoding problem! In my localhost project **UTF-8** works fine (Windows 7 with Wamp) but at linux CentOS server the UTF-8 does not work, i had to save all files as "**ANSI as UTF-8**" (without BOM).

Answer (score 3):

I've had the same problem with my application.

Check this:

1.) Inside your **controllers**, check is there anything before your `<?php` tags (**BOM**). I was always checking with **vim**.

2.) Check if your `tmp` folder is writable. (`chmod -R 777 app/tmp`)

3.) Check if theres an updated version of PHP installed on your server.

Maybe you should check 2.) first.

Comment: no characters before <?php tag .... tmp folder is writable, php updated .... not working anyway

Comment: If the application is not something private (job or something like that) you can send it to my e-mail and I'll try deploying it on a server and we'll see if it works. Application will be deleted after the test.

Comment: Number 2 solved my issue which is opening cached page behind admin rout, and it may corrupt some functionality depends on session.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a different method to store sessions?

Cake by default uses fileEngine, but if permissions are screwed up or there's error writing to files, you can store sessions via mySQL.

I think there is a field to set sessions to MEMORY or DATABASE, instead of FileEngine.