# CakePHP Session difference between Mac and Windows

Tags: php, cakephp

I am using cakePHP 2.4 on windows running WAMP with no issues.

As soon as I move the source code over to Mac running WAMP I get errors regarding the headers being already sent.

Has anyone come across this before?

```
Warning (2): session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/cskplay/app/Controller/UsersController.php:2) [APP/Vendor/facebook-php-sdk-master/src/facebook.php, line 49]
```

I have already tried everything in this post:

[CakePHP 2.x sessions behaving inconsistently between local dev and production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15257265/cakephp-2-x-sessions-behaving-inconsistently-between-local-dev-and-production)

Comment: Are you sure that nothing has been sent to the browser before starting the session?  Even trailing whitespace after a `?>` in a PHP file that is being included can cause output (and subsequently headers) to be sent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed! It was an empty line between the start of a controller and the opening `<?`.

strange how it only mattered on Mac not windows.

Comment: Could be a number of reasons. Different `error_reporting` directives between the two environments most likely.

Comment: hi paul, you answer is correct. but finding space in project is hard task. do you any short way to do this?