# Multiple administrators login with PHP

Tags: php, session, cookies, authentication, multi-user

I am trying to create a PHP website with more than one administrator. I have some doubts

1. How can I check if an admin is logged in? I know I must use sessions for security reasons, but how can I recognize which one of the administrators is logged in?
2. Should I set a `$_SESSION['username']` variable when `username` performs login and send a cookie containing `username` too? This way, I know who is him (or pretends to be) and can check if `username` is actually logged in, checking `$_SESSION['username']` before showing pages. Is it secure?

Comment: Why don't you store data in DB ( and delete it, when the admin has logged off ) and check there?

Comment: For your first question, `function isLoggedIn() { return isset($_SESSION['username']); }` will do the trick.

Comment: I'm voting to put on hold as too broad, though - I think you would be better off looking at a tutorial on the web. The learning of these broad topics is better taken from a book or tutorial and doing some solid study (imo), and any answer that writes the necessary book as an answer would be an exercise in duplication.

Comment: I think you should learn some framework - if not for future use then for the grasp of the basic concepts.

Comment: @halfer Unfortunately I haven't found much about multiple administrators websites, do you know any online tutorial on this topic? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Extra tip dont trust $_SESSION to be safe out off the box.. Mine post here explains why..  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18262878/how-to-prevent-php-sessions-being-shared-between-different-apache-vhosts/18263063#18263063

Comment: There's bound to be something on this site about it, but I'd do it just by recording something in the session. So record `users.is_admin` in `$_SESSION['is_admin']` and then permit or deny operations based on this flag. You can then have as many administrator users as you like.

Comment: @halfer so if I've understood correctly, when an admin logs in you would set both `$_SESSION['is_admin']` and `$_SESSION['username']`. I check `$_SESSION['is_admin']` to know if any of the administrators is logged in. But if two administrators are logged in, both `$_SESSION['admin1_username']` and `$_SESSION['admin2_username']` are set... how can I distinguish if the page is requested from admin1 or admin2? Sorry for the dumb question but I'm a bit confused.

Comment: If there are both admins, do you need to differentiate them? Are you sure they are not administrators of different types? - in that case, your user type is not a boolean as I've sugested, it is a string or an int. You could have (`user`, `superuser`, `moderator`, `admin`), for example.

Comment: @halfer I've noticed the question has been put on hold from your request. It's too broad, I agree. To narrow it to the topic title, I've restricted it to questions n.1 and n.2 (I think these points are sufficient to cover all the requests and significantly restrict the problem). I hope it's ok now. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Giorgio. Yes, it was put on hold at the request of five of us (listed below) - only moderators have the power to close on their own. The question should stay undeleted, since it doesn't drop below -2 score. It could be reopened now, but in any case it seems you received the answer you need - RoyalBg spotted what info you were missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I check if an admin is logged in? I know I must use sessions
>   for security reasons, but how can I recognize which one of the
>   administrators is logged in?

Same way as you check if a normal user is logged in. A session, ofcourse. Both, normal user and administrator should have `$_SESSION['username']` set in. To make someone administrator, I guess, you are using a flag in the db, let's say the column is `access_level`. ENUMs are `1` => user, `2` => adminitrator. So when you login the user, put into session this one too. `$_SESSION['access_level']` will tell you if this user is admin, and `$_SESSION['username']` will tell you its username.

> Should I set a $_SESSION['username'] variable when username performs
>   login and send a cookie containing username too? This way, I know who
>   is him (or pretends to be) and can check if username is actually
>   logged in, checking $_SESSION['username'] before showing pages. Is it
>   secure?

Sessions are enough. They do set cookies on client site aswell. Do not store additional `$_COOKIE['username']`.

> I am using a MVC structure, so I would like to build something (a
>   model, a controller) to use it also for login / check credentials /
>   logout operations. Which is the most elegant (object oriented) way to
>   achieve it?

In a few words - a model method for login. If user is admin, normal, etc, could be done by the controller by using the extract of the model, which queries the DB taking username, password, access_level, etc.

```
const USER_NORMAL = 1;
const USER_ADMIN = 2;

public function isAdmin() {
    $row = $this->_application->UserModel->login();
    if($row['access_level'] == self::USER_ADMIN) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

> I have some scripts (i.e. a "upload.php" script, to let admins to
>   upload files) which can be only accessed if one of the admins is
>   logged in. These scripts are not views, so I can't check login (my
>   intention was to check login on controller level, before showing
>   pages). So how can I do in this case?

So check on controller as you wish, with the method above.

```
if(!$this->UserController->isAdmin()) {
    header("Location: index.php");
}
else {
   // show page
}
```

Comment: Note taken. Edited with quote blocks. Thank you :)

Comment: Thanks for the accurate answer. I'm not sure to have understood your hint on `access_level`. I mean: suppose that an administrator (called peter) logs in, in this case I would set a `$_SESSION['peter']=true` and `$_SESSION['access_level']=2`. But if a user logs in after him, since `$_SESSION['access_level']` is unique on server-side, I would overwrite it with value 1. Am I missing something?

Comment: You are missing something. Sessions are bound to session_id. In this case you will not overwrite. That's why it's allowed to have `$_SESSION['username'] = 'peter'` as long as the session is on the session_id where 'peter' works. If 'john' logs in. you will set `$_SESSION['username'] = 'john'` and will not overwrite anything. You will have two separate `$_SESSION['username']`. `$_SESSION['peter']` seems the wrong way for me :)

Comment: I was really missing the basis, you're right! Thanks so much for the clarification.

Comment: Good stuff Royal. To add to this @Giorgio, sessions are powered by unique cookies that the browser and PHP exchange fairly transparently. These are stored in the file system (by default) and store the user's session vars as serialised strings. Note that sessions _might_ have security problems in shared hosts, by virtue of these files being readable by other customers of that host. So, if you are on a shared host, make sure the web server runs as _your_ user, not a generic "www" user, so the files it writes are not accessible to other users on the same box. Ask the host if you're not sure.

Answer (score 0):

1. you should set session for username and password (which get from login form)
   Then, you connect to mysql and check if user_name_field = "username" && password_field = "passowrd" => user logged
   Etc : "SELECT user_id,user_name FROM users WHERE user_name = "ABC" AND user_pass = "123456"
   This sql maybe return a empty array or one-element array. If empty array => logging not pass
   else => logged
2. you need set session or cookie only, should know that : facebook.com save password and userid = cookie. You dont worry about cookie is not secure
3. in MVC struct, you should build 1 view to view login form, 1 function in a controller class to get username, password, 1 model function to connect and query sql, return array result for that controller.
   That proccess : user action in view, view send data to controller, controller use data connect to database with model, and get result from model to return for view
4. you should return false or redirect or alert when any user not admin which access upload page

P/s : sorry if my english bother you. i just use Google translate