# How to update a record with SQL

Tags: php, pdo, sql-update

I'm trying to update a username record, with the new one that comes from form.

After I execute the statement, a record in my database is deleted but it is NOT REPLACED with a new one, that comes from form. I can not figure out why.

index.php:

```
<form action="change.php">
    <input type="text" name="txtNewUsername" id="txtNewUsername" placeholder="new username"><br/>
    <button>Change username</button>
</form>
```

change.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once __DIR__.'/connect.php';

$txtNewUsername = $_POST['txtNewUsername'];
$sUsername = $_SESSION['txtUsername'];

try{
    $stmt = $db->prepare('UPDATE users SET username = :sNewUsername WHERE username = :sOldUsername');
    $stmt->bindValue('sNewUsername', $txtNewUsername);
    $stmt->bindValue(':sOldUsername', $sUsername);
    $stmt->execute();

    echo $txtNewUsername;


}catch(PDOEXception $ex){
    echo $ex;
}
```

I would like to replace the username of connected user with the one coming from a form.

Comment: This also assumes PHP sessions are always safe (which they are not) and unedited by external "virtual webhost users" see [How to prevent PHP sessions being shared between different apache vhosts? (answer off mine)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18262878/how-to-prevent-php-sessions-being-shared-between-different-apache-vhosts/18263063#18263063).. the SQL injection is not possible as you are using prepared statements as you should but it might be possible to change the username of a other user in some bad configuration cases if the session files are stored in one directory on the webserver

Answer (score 0):

```
$stmt->bindValue('sNewUsername', $txtNewUsername);
```

I don't know if this is causing your problem but you are missing " : " sNewUsername

Comment: It is not required.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I see is that you have no form **method** specified. Without a `method=?` the default is **GET**. [Read about it here](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.3)

You are trying to retrieve the *updated* value using **POST**

Change `<form action="change.php">` to `<form action="change.php" method="post">`

With everything said... since using a `get` method is an easy hack, it is better to use `post` when passing information from one page to another.

You may also want to change `<button>Change username</button>` to `<input type="button" name="submit" value="Change username" />`