# how can I select and display all the rows from the same user, underneath each other with php

Tags: php, mysql, echo

Users can add their workouts into a database. There will have more than one workout per user. How can i display the workout names for the logged in user, underneath each other? I have no problem adding the workouts. When I echo the names of the added workouts, it display right next to each other like "workout1workout2". I want to be able to display the workouts underneath each other. I have no idea how to do it. It would be best if I could display each workout as a button.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM info WHERE username='$_SESSION[username]' ";
$results = mysqli_query($db, $query);
while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {
    echo $data['workout'];
}
```

Comment: Offtopic: Don't ever assume the SESSION array to be safe because it's not especially on shared hosts (with bad configs), [this post of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18262878/how-to-prevent-php-sessions-being-shared-between-different-apache-vhosts/18263063#18263063) explains why

Comment: Always use prepared statements when quering a database make no exceptions even when it seams to be "safe" ... See [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you shouldn't put that username in query like that. Look into SQL Injection and how to avoid that in PHP.

As for displaying buttons/workouts. You can embed HTML code inside the echo statement like below. You can add any html like that and it will render HTML.

```
   $query = "SELECT * FROM info WHERE username='$_SESSION[username]' ";
   $results = mysqli_query($db, $query);
   while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {
   echo "<button>$data['workout']</button></br>";
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

$query = "SELECT * FROM info WHERE username='$_SESSION[username]' Group  By username";

Comment: Mind the SQL injections.. Also `SELECT * .. GROUP BY column` is general wrong SQL to write..