# How to pass multiple columns to a variable in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm working on a project which requires more than one column contents to be passed to a php variable

I am able to select and pass one column content to the variable but failed on multiple columns

```
$myEMPNEM = "";

$sqlNEM = "SELECT first_name, middle_name, last_name, job_title FROM 
t_employees WHERE user_name = '" . $_SESSION["uname"] . "'";
$resultNEM = mysqli_query( $conn, $sqlNEM );
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultNEM))
{
  $myEMPNEM = $row['first_name'];   
 }
```

I expect more than one column content to be passed to the php variable

Comment: To which PHP variable?

Comment: You are only assigning first_name.  Why would you expect more?

Comment: The  $myEMPNEM  variable

Comment: What are you expecting to be assigned to that variable?

Comment: i would prefer to assign first_name, middle_name, last_name and job_title

Comment: Have you tried `$row['middle_name']`? or any of the other columns?

Comment: Don't assume `$_SESSION` array to be safe, because it might not be the case on [shared webhosting (with bad configurations)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18263063/2548147) .. General rule when working with a database always always always always always always always always use [prepared statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1) **no exceptions**

Comment: Thank you @RaymondNijland i will work on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either need to use the variable as an array:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultNEM))
{
  $myEMPNEM = array($row['first_name'], $row['middle_name'], $row['last_name']);   
}
```

Or concatenate the values together into a single string:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultNEM))
{
  $myEMPNEM = $row['first_name'] . " " . $row['middle_name'] . " " . $row['last_name'];
}
```

Comment: Concatenating the values together into a string works! I appreciate