# session_start() failed to decode session object. session has been destroyed error

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a logout issue,

I applied below line in codeigniter config file:

```
$config['sess_save_path'] = sys_get_temp_dir();
```

Why do I get this error?

> session_start(): failed to decode session object. session has been
>   destroyed. filename: session/session.php

Comment: did u included `session` in `libraries`

Comment: *"Proof-read before posting!

Now that you're ready to ask your question, take a deep breath and read through it from start to finish. Pretend you're seeing it for the first time: does it make sense? Try reproducing the problem yourself, in a fresh environment and make sure you can do so using only the information included in your question. Add any details you missed and read through it again."* ... See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: ... as your question is totally not clear as we have no idea for starters how you configured your sessions to work.. Not to mention how the code looks like..

Comment: .. also i would strongly disadvice using `sys_get_temp_dir()` security wise -> a post of mine explains [why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18262878/how-to-prevent-php-sessions-being-shared-between-different-apache-vhosts/18263063#18263063) as answer on *"How to prevent PHP sessions being shared between different apache vhosts?"* you can read websites instead of vhosts...