# A way to avoid stocking plain text password in both session and database

Tags: php, mysql, security, hash, passwords

Here is an idea I've got to store no plain text password in both session and SQL (even if needed in post). Can you tell me what you do think about this way to proceed ?

```
//The password entered by user in plain text
$password = $_POST['password'];

//Get data
$req = $db -> prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE uid = ?');
$req -> execute(array($_POST['uid']));
$data = $req -> fetch();

//Verifying password
if(password_verify($password, $data['hashed_password']))
{
     $_SESSION['rehash'] = password_hash($data['hashed_password'], PASSWORD_DEFAUT);
     $_SESSION['uid'] = $_POST['uid'];
}
```

---

```
//When checking credentials on other pages of the website:
if(password_verify($data['hashed_password'], $_SESSION['rehash'])
{
     //Private things here
}
```

I've seen a lot of topics on the same type of subject, and even if I don't think so, if this is a duplicate, feel free to close this topic.

Comment: Since Sessions are stored serverside; I'm not qutie sure what the purpose of this is. If a session is set, that's because I've allowed it to be set. Usually I set the userid in the session.

Comment: @IsThisJavascript and topicstarter, information which can identify a user like id's and (re)hashes is not right to store in PHP sessions as these are not safe in default configuration far from safe...i once wrote this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18263063/2548147) how $_SESSION can be attacked

Comment: Interesting read. Thanks for educating

Comment: I don't understand why do you need that rehash? It seems completely unnecessary.

Comment: It avoids me to store a plain text password in session or sql db, witch are both unsecured and stealable. If someone steals my hash/rehash, it's okay because I could change the stored hash after a relog for example, so it would make it harder to hack  someone.