# CakePHP: Unable to find Auth data in $_SESSION

Tags: php, session, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, session-variables

I'm doing some basic integration between a CakePHP app and some external code. I want the external code to know if a user is logged in. The external code does not load CakePHP, so thought I would access that data directly using `$_SESSION`, but when I dump it it's an empty array, even when I'm logged into CakePHP.

Am I missing something? Why isn't the session data from CakePHP showing up?

Comment: Is this "external code" located on another (v)host or on the same host?

Answer (score 0):

You might need to play with your session ids and session name variables to get your external code to load the CakePHP session information.

For example, you will almost certainly need this:

```
session_name('CAKEPHP');
```

and you might need to pass across the session id from Cake, and possibly set the session save path as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can read http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/admad/2009/09/02/how-to-bend-cakephp-s-session-handling-to-your-needs

It will examplain you how to bend your cakephp session according to your need.

OR

You can see one more link which will solve your problem [Use cakephp session with two different domains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18187658/use-cakephp-session-with-two-different-domains)

Hope these two links will solve your problem!