# Use php cookie in all sub domain

Tags: php, wordpress, session, cakephp, cookies

I am using `cakephp 2.x` for my main application and `wordpress` for blog, now my main application is on my domain called `example.com` and my blog is in sub domain called `blog.example.com`. i want to login user in my blog site also when user login in my main site (`example.com`).

in cakephp i have use

```
ini_set('session.cookie_domain', '.example.com');
```

in my `myapp/app/Config/bootstrap.php`

and

```
$this->Cookie->domain = '.example.com';
```

in `beforeFilter()` of my `appController`

while in `WP` i had used

```
define('COOKIE_DOMAIN', 'example.com');
```

Now scenario is,

1. When i open `example.com` first and login with my username/password and then after i open `blog.example.com` then my blog site show me as logged in user (i have just different header menu for logged in user and not-logged in user)
2. When i open my `blog.example.com` first, then after i open `example.com` and login in `example.com` and refresh the `blog.example.com` then it won't display header for login user(i.e not login the user, means not detecting the session cookie of main domain).

i determine the logic like (i'm not sure but), if wp site open up first then it create it's own session cookie and if cakephp site open first then wp site uses session cookie from that. but what for `point 2`.

can anyone help me please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
header("Set-Cookie: cookiename=cookievalue; expires=thus, 14-march-2015 23:39:49 GMT; path=/; domain=subdomain.example.net");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this :

```
    $this->Cookie->write('cookien_name','data array',true,'time');
```

This is not necessary to set domain name.if you not set domain name then it auto save domain name as '/'. 
Please check this url also. 
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/cookie.html

Comment: my aim is not to write cookie. i have mention that i want use use common login, and for that we have to share cookie generated by session.

Comment: check this url hope this can be hep : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15188261/single-sign-on-sso-between-wordpress-and-cakephp